# Configurable HTTP/S redirection

Tags: http, redirect, ip, cloud, load-balancing

For an IoT deployment, I am looking to redirect requests to my custom domain to a different URL based on the **source IP**, i.e. I will have a small number of allowed clients with known public IPs hitting a URL - `https://www.example.com`, and each one needs redirecting to a unique URL. The target URL is not neccesarily a domain landing page, so I can't use anything DNS-based.

I would ideally want to use some kind of online API/service. It will be frequently reconfigured by a non-programmer user, so it needs to be as easy to configure as possible.

I've checked out URL redirecting services, load balancing services, and CDNs but I can't seem to find something that will redirect based on inspecting the source IP.